# Finding the orthogonal basis, picture included!

Tags: linear-algebra

I decided to share a picture of what I have so far. I am not sure if I did it correctly and sorry if it is 
not readable. Ask me if anything is unclear. In the exercise I am basically just asked to find the ortogonal basis. I did it by finding the reduced echelon form of the matrix A to see which columns form the basis and then I used the Gram Schmidt process on these columns. [image]

Comment: As it is now, there is unfortunately no picture.

Comment: Sorry I am trying to fix it but it won't upload. I will try to post an URL instead

Comment: Perhaps the picture is too big?

Comment: There it is! Just rotate it and it will be fine.

Comment: It works now I just had to wait, I submitted the question too fast. However it is in the wrong direction. Is it readable?

Comment: Nope, you need to rotate the picture in a program of your own (this website can't do it) and then upload it again.

Comment: basis for what subspace?

Comment: Here, now it should work! Apparently it was too long. Anyways, I have the matrix A and I am asked to find the ortogonal basis for A. A is as in the picture.

Comment: @abel I need to find it for A. I guessed they they wanted me to look at col(A) and find the basis for this and afterwards use the Gram Schmidt process on the vectors that formed the basis. Is this correct? The picture should be working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you have is one orthogonal basis for the column space of $A.$ here is another one $\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}, \pmatrix{1\\0\\1}.$

Comment: How did you find this one?

Comment: @Husky653, i took a multiple of the second column as the first vector in the basis. now it is easier to project the first column onto this.

Comment: Ah okay yes of course, but my procedure above is correct still or? I read in the book and looked at the examples and I think it is correct but I just want it confirmed.

Comment: @Husky653, yes, your procedure is correct. a subspace has lots of basis.